# Can the composite pattern be used to generate HTML from a tree and handle the indenting as well, or this inherently not possible?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, composite, category-theory, monoids

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWDmWbJ4wRA&list=PLrhzvIcii6GNjpARdnO4ueTUAVR9eMBpc&index=21) on the composite pattern, where the main example is how to use the pattern as a mean to generate HTML code from a tree structure describing a todo list where each item can be in turn a todo list, and it seems a convenient test-bed, so here it is a target HTML:

```html
[ ] Main
<ul>
  <li>[ ] 1.</li>
  <li>[ ] 2.
    <ul>
      <li>[ ] 2.1</li>
      <li>[ ] 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>[ ] 3.</li>
</ul>
```

(Sorry if the top `[ ] Main` doesn't make sense, but I don't know HTML; furthermore that's irrelevant to my question, I believe.)

I understand that design patterns are mostly an OOP "thing", however I'm often referring to the article [*Design Patterns in Haskell*](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/05/design-patterns-in-haskel/) to understand how they can be reinterpreted in functional programming, with the aim of understanding them at a deeper level.

As regards the *composite pattern*, that article essentially reads:

> Composite. **Recursive algebraic data types.** Especially prominent since there's no built-in inheritance.

Therefore I thought it would be easy to try it in Haskell, and I came up with this code:

```hs
import Data.List (intercalate)

data Todo = Todo String | TodoList String [Todo] deriving Show

showList' :: Todo -> String
showList' (Todo s) = "[ ] " ++ s
showList' (TodoList s ts) = "[ ] " ++ s
                          ++ "<ul><li>"
                          ++ intercalate "</li><li>" (map showList' ts)
                          ++ "</li></ul>"
```

which, fed like this

```hs
putStrLn $ showList' $ TodoList "Main" [Todo "1.", TodoList "2." [Todo "2.1", Todo "2.2"], Todo "3."]
```

generates this output

```html
[ ] Main<ul><li>[ ] 1.</li><li>[ ] 2.<ul><li>[ ] 2.1</li><li>[ ] 2.2</li></ul></li><li>[ ] 3.</li></ul>
```

which is essentially the HTML at the top of my question rendered on a single line: it's clear from my implementation of `showList'` that once a call to it (at any depth of the recusion) returns a string, that string is not altered in any way, just concateneted with others. So I feel that there's isn't much I can do to make `showList'` add `\n` and spaces to reach the nicely formatted HTML.

I've tried a bit, adding spaces and `\n`, but especially upon reading [*Composite as a monoid*](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/12/composite-as-a-monoid/) by [Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126014/mark-seemann) I start do be a bit doubtful about the feasibility of what I'm trying to do...

I'm tempted to reach the conclusion that **if composite is a monoid, it means that the various items are combined two by two in the same way *regardless of their depth in the tree***, and so this means that adding space for a nice formatting is not possible because the amount of space to be added depends on the context surrounding the two elements being concatenated, and not just on the two elements.

However, I'm not really sure about my reasoning, hence I'm asking here.

Comment: on first glance it seems that not too hard to extend: add a `depth` parameter to `showList'`, use it for indentation and increase it on the inner/recursive `map (showLists' (depth+1))` call

Answer (score 5):

This answer is a bit roundabout. (The comments already contain a perfectly valid and more straightforward suggestion.)

We can define this auxiliary type:

```
data Todo' a = Todo' String 
             | TodoList' String [a] 
             deriving Show
```

It's like `Todo`, but in the "recursive" step, instead of another `Todo`, we have a polymorphic value. We can put anything we wish there, including the original `Todo`:

```
peel :: Todo -> Todo' Todo
peel todo = case todo of
    Todo s -> Todo' s 
    TodoList s xs -> TodoList' s xs
```

Why on earth would we want to do this? Well, sometimes we want to talk about a single "layer" of a recursive datatype, leaving open the question of what the layers below might contain.

Now we are going to reconstruct `showList'` in another way. First, this auxiliary function `cata`:

```
cata :: (Todo' a -> a) -> Todo -> a
cata f todo  = case peel todo of 
    Todo' s -> f (Todo' s)
    TodoList' s xs -> f (TodoList' s (map (cata f) xs))
```

This function says that, if we have a way to convert a single `Todo'` layer carrying some kind of result from the lower layers into a result for the current layer, then we are able to convert an entire `Todo` value into a result.

`showList'` can now be written as

```
showList'' :: Todo -> String
showList'' todo = cata layer todo
  where
  layer :: Todo' String -> String
  layer (Todo' s) = "[ ] " ++ s
  layer (TodoList' s xs) = "[ ] " ++ s
                           ++ "<ul><li>"
                           ++ intercalate "</li><li>" xs
                           ++ "</li></ul>"
```

Notice that this version doesn't have explicit recursion, `cata` takes care of it.

Ok. Now, as you mention, the problem with indenting is that the result of one layer depends on the number of layers that are above. The most natural way of expressing such dependency in Haskell is with a function of type `Int -> String`, where the `Int` is the number of layers above.

When we wrote `showList'`, me made `cata` return a `String`. What if we made it return a function `Int -> String` instead?

```
showIndented :: Todo -> String
showIndented todo = cata layer todo 0
  where
  layer :: Todo' (Int -> String) -> Int -> String
  layer todo' indentation = 
    let tabs =  replicate indentation '\t'
     in case todo' of
        Todo' s -> 
            tabs ++  "<li>[ ] " ++ s ++ "</li>\n"
        TodoList' s fs ->
            tabs ++ "[ ] " ++ s ++ "\n" ++
            tabs ++ "<ul>\n" ++ 
            foldMap ($ succ indentation) fs ++ 
            tabs ++ "</ul>\n"
```

The `foldMap ($ succ indentation) xs` bit is taking a list of functions, calling all of them with the current level of indentation + 1, and concatenating the resulting strings.

Comment: The `cata` function is a "catamorphism" https://blog.sumtypeofway.com/posts/introduction-to-recursion-schemes.html Usually the recursive form of the datatype is derived from the single-layer form using a type combinator called `Fix` but we didn't to that here for simplicity. Catamorphism "destroy" a data structure starting for the leaves; making the catamorphism return a function is a trick in the "folklore" for allowing the downward flow of information (in this case, the indentation level).

Comment: ...why have you gone the open recursion route at all? What part of this answer could *not* be done or said with the original data type and no extras? (I personally don't see any such part.)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you're expecting the `Monoid` or *Composite* abstraction to do something that it can't do. If there's a way to implement the desired functionality (indentation) using *only* the `Monoid` type class, I'm not aware of it...

This would be the same case, I think, with the Composite design pattern. In an object-oriented setting, how would you implement indentation with Composite?

That's not entirely clear to me, but then, I suppose it depends on how you'd want to implement something like the `Todo` type in object-oriented programming (OOP). In OOP, you typically model *behaviour*, whereas the `Todo` type here is a sum type, which can be [mapped to a Visitor in OOP](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/25/visitor-as-a-sum-type). I wonder, however, if this isn't a bit of a distraction.

A *Composite* is an object that 'makes many objects look like a single object'. If you squint hard enough, that fits the `Semigroup` and `Monoid` operations with the type `a -> a -> a`, or even better, their aggregation functions [sconcat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#v:sconcat) and [mconcat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mconcat), of which the latter has the type `[a] -> a`. Expressed in a more loose way, it enables us to take any number of `a` values and turn them into a single `a` - it makes many `a` look like a single `a`.

What you seem to be looking for here is rather a function that can digest a data structure into a potentially more compact value. Specifically, you're looking for `Todo -> String`, but more abstractly a function which in pseudo-Haskell we could attempt to describe as `Complex -> Simple`.

As danidiaz describes in [his or her awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67042881/126014), this looks more like a [catamorphism](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/04/29/catamorphisms). I'm deeply indebted to danidiaz for the following.

Before I read that answer, I figured that the `Todo` catamorphism would more naturally look like this:

```
foldTodo :: (String -> a) -> (String -> [a] -> a) -> Todo -> a
foldTodo leaf    _     (Todo s)       = leaf s
foldTodo leaf list (TodoList s todos) = list s $ foldTodo leaf list <$> todos
```

As you can tell, I decided to name it `foldTodo`, since there's a (weak) convention in Haskell that catamorphisms are often named like `foldXyz`.

That function is the central abstraction. The rest is just rendering functionality, starting with a little helper function to indent text:

```
indent :: Int -> String
indent n = replicate (2 * n) ' '
```

This function uses two spaces for each indentation, rather than a tab, as danidiaz does it.

Here's a function to render the leaf node in the `Todo` sum type:

```
renderLeaf :: String -> Int -> String
renderLeaf s depth = indent depth ++ "<li>[ ] " ++ s ++ "</li>\n"
```

And here's the corresponding function to render a (sub)list:

```
renderList :: String -> [Int -> String] -> Int -> String
renderList s fs depth =
  indent depth ++ "[ ] " ++ s ++ "\n" ++
  indent depth ++ "<ul>\n" ++ 
  foldMap ($ succ depth) fs ++
  indent depth ++ "</ul>\n"
```

As you can tell, I stole these two functions from danidiaz's
`layer` function. I'd never thought about this myself, by it's a neat trick to use the catamorphism to convert the data structure to a function that takes the `depth` as input.

We can now use the catamorphism to render a `Todo` list:

```
render :: Todo -> String
render todo = foldTodo renderLeaf renderList todo 0
```

The `foldTodo renderLeaf renderList todo` part returns a function with the type `Int -> String` because that's what both `renderLeaf` and `renderList` return. This function can then be called with the top-level depth of `0` to return a `String`.

As far as I can tell, it works as intended:

```
> putStrLn $ render $ TodoList "Main" [Todo "1.", TodoList "2." [Todo "2.1", Todo "2.2"], Todo "3."]
[ ] Main
<ul>
  <li>[ ] 1.</li>
  [ ] 2.
  <ul>
    <li>[ ] 2.1</li>
    <li>[ ] 2.2</li>
  </ul>
  <li>[ ] 3.</li>
</ul>
```

To conclude, I still think that my theorem that [Composites are monoids](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/12/composite-as-a-monoid) holds, but notice that I didn't claim that all monoids are Composites.

The `Todo` type in the OP isn't a `Monoid` instance, but as far as I can tell, it could be. I'm still not convinced that this would be sufficient to implement the desired functionality.

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer is the reason why I asked the question. If, as you say, _composites are monoids_, then one can't expect from a _composite_ to be helpful in a scenario where a _monoid_ isn't, right? So if the a _monoid_ can't handle the indentation when "adding up" elements together (which is kind of clear to me: _I'm tempted to reach the conclusion_), then the composite pattern surely can't. And so, whatever I do to put elements together **and** handle the indentation, that's not the composite pattern. Am I summarizing correctly your thought?

Comment: @Enlico Yes, that seems to summarise my thoughts well. FTR, I don't claim that it's *impossible* to reach the desired goal with a Composite; only that I currently fail to see how that'd be possible. But then again, until a few days ago, I was unaware of danidiaz's beutiful trick... I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. The other answers are really, really complicated, while it *can* be completely straightforward. You just implement a helper function that takes the amount of indentation (other answers represented this as an `Int`, I'll represent it as the `String` that `Int` corresponds to, but that's only a surface-level difference), and use the exact same pattern of pattern-matching-and-recursion as in the original code.

I'm going to use `printf`, but just because I find a lot of string concatenation ugly, not because it's fundamentally needed.

```
import Text.Printf

data Todo = Todo String | TodoList String [Todo] deriving Show

showList' :: Todo -> String
showList' = printf "<ul>\n%s</ul>" . go "  " where
    go :: String -> Todo -> String
    go indentation (Todo s) = printf "%s<li>[ ] %s</li>\n" indentation s
    go indentation (TodoList s ts) = printf
        "%s<li>[ ] %s\n  %s<ul>\n%s  %s</ul>\n%s</li>\n"
        indentation
        s
        indentation
        (concatMap (go ("    " ++ indentation)) ts) -- concatMap and foldMap are the same thing here, use whichever you like better
        indentation
        indentation
```

Again, the main two differences here are: my recursive helper `go` has an extra argument, and instead of `intercalate` I use `concatMap`.

Trying it out in ghci, with the same test list as you had:

```
> putStrLn . showList' $ TodoList "Main" [Todo "1.", TodoList "2." [Todo "2.1", Todo "2.2"], Todo "3."]
<ul>
  <li>[ ] Main
    <ul>
      <li>[ ] 1.</li>
      <li>[ ] 2.
        <ul>
          <li>[ ] 2.1</li>
          <li>[ ] 2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>[ ] 3.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

While @MarkSeeman's blog post and answer here are thought-provoking, I'm not convinced that the *Composite*-as-`Monoid` approach is particularly helpful in general, even if there's some formal sense in which all *Composite*s can be written monoidally.  The original gang-of-four description of *Composite* is a **tree** of objects that can be treated uniformly.  If *Composite*s were intended to be monoidal, wouldn't this be a **list** of objects rather than a tree?

Now, there are *some* cases where, for a particular *Composite*, the tree structure is incidental and the *Composite* is naturally monoidal (e.g., maybe serializations or builders).  In those cases, recognizing this may lead naturally to a Haskell implementation that's cleaner than the obvious OO implementation.  However, where the tree structure is significant (e.g., indented to-do lists), trying to shoehorn it into a `Monoid` doesn't seem to buy you much.

Getting back to your data type:

```
data Todo = Todo String | TodoList String [Todo] deriving Show
```

This seems to be exactly the right recursive data type to represent to-do lists as a *Composite*.

In particular, an idiomatic OO implementation would involve a `TodoItem` item class (a "primitive"), a `TodoList` item class (a "container"), and some separate `TodoObject` abstract superclass to allow uniform treatment of primitives, containers, and containers of containers.

The usual mapping of class hiearchies like this to Haskell is to map the concrete classes to constructors, and the abstract class to the type for those constructors, and that's exactly what you've done, up to the specific choice of names:

```
data TodoObject = TodoItem String | TodoList String [TodoObject]
```

This is why [the Haskell Design Patterns link](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/05/design-patterns-in-haskel/) spends all of two sentences on *Composites*.  They are naturally expressed as recursive data types.  End of story.

Well, maybe not "end of story".  If you want to operate on such Haskell *Composites* algorithmically (e.g., rendering a `Todo` with indentation) in an idiomatic way, then you want to use the usual tools for working with recursive data types.  These usually involve hand-coded catamorphisms:

```
myCata :: ToDo -> Result
myCata (Todo x) = ...result for this primitive...
myCata (TodoList x items) = let results = map myCata items in
    ...some result based on `results` for the contents...
```

where you're allowed to pass "state" through the recursion, using extra arguments for example.  One of the advantages of a hand-coded catamorphism over a higher-order `foldTodo` function is that you don't have to introduce more complex mechanisms  to implement basic tasks like indenting some text, like lifting a polymorphic type from `Todo Todo` to `Todo (Int -> Todo)` or introducing a `Traversable` type class and a `Reader` applicative, or whatever.

In other words, I think @DanielWagner's solution is an appropriate "real world" solution and more likely to be found in the wild than the solutions given in the other answers (which I think were intended to illustrate a point anyway, rather than offer a serious solution for your indentation problem).

My own solution is a little different.  You may find it interesting, as it uses the original data type and implements indentation through post-processing of rendered blocks of lines rather than passing indentation as an argument and returning a single, multi-line `String`.  I think this makes it more idiomatic as a functional programming solution, though possibly less performant.

```
data Todo = Todo String | TodoList String [Todo] deriving Show

render :: Todo -> [String]
render (Todo s) = ["[ ] " ++ s]
render (TodoList s items)
  =  [ "[ ] " ++ s
     , "<ul>" ]
  ++      indent (concat rendered_lis)
  ++ [ "</ul>" ]
  where rendered_lis = make_li . render <$> items

        -- indent a block of lines
        indent = map ("  " ++)
        -- make a block of lines into an <li> item
        --   - case for one line
        make_li [s] = ["<li>" ++ s ++ "</li>"]
        --   - case for multi-line
        make_li (s:ss)
          =  ["<li>" ++ s]
          ++     indent ss
          ++ ["</li>"]

showList' = unlines . render
```